# Nonlinear PDE with a trivial and nontrivial solutions: how to?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am solving the following PDE:

```
eqMain = D[z[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[ z[x, y], {y, 2}] - 
    (a - x/(x^2 + y^2 + 0.0001))*z[x, y] - z[x, y]^3==0;
```

with the zero Dirichlet boundary conditions.

It should be explained that this equation has two solutions. One of them is non-trivial. It is this solution that I am looking for. The other solution is trivial: `z[x,y]==0`. The latter, in combination with zero boundary conditions, gives rise to difficulty. Namely, the solver always selects the trivial solution due to zero boundary conditions.

There is a workaround, however. The equation can be solved by the relaxation method. Within this method, one introduces a pseudo-time, t, and solves the following time-dependent equation:

```
eqTimeDep = D[z[t, x, y], t] == 
   D[z[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + 
    D[ z[t, x, y], {y, 2}] - (a - x/(x^2 + y^2 + 0.0001))*z[t, x, y] -
     z[t, x, y]^3;
```

The pseudo-time-dependent equation's solution converges to the stationary equation's solution at large t.

For more information about the relaxation approach to solving such equations see A. Boulbitch "Pseudo-dynamic approach to the numerical solution of nonlinear differential equations" Mathematica J. (2018).

For example:

```
a = 0.001;
L = 5;
T = 100;
bc = {z[t, -L, y] == z[t, L + 10, y] == 0,  
   z[t, x, -L] == z[t, x, L] == 0, 
   z[0, x, y] == 
    If[0.001*Exp[-x^2 + y^2] < 10^-6, 0, 0.001*Exp[-x^2 + y^2]]};
sol = NDSolve[{eqTimeDep, bc}, z, {t, 0, T}, {x, -L, L + 10}, {y, -L, L}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxStepSize -> 0.1, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, 
        "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}] // Quiet;
```

This more or less works and gives the following solution:

```
 Plot3D[
 Evaluate[sol[[1, 1, 2]][T, x, y]], {x, -L, L + 10}, {y, -L, L}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.75, ImageSize -> 300, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16], Style["y", 16], Style["z", 16]}]
```

[image]

This solution looks like what I expected.

However, it is a very time-consuming method. It would be much better and faster if I could solve the stationary equation directly.

The following approach I have tried:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
R = DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {15, 5}], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.0005*(1 + 40 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]];
```

[image]

```
ndslv = NDSolveValue[{D[z[x, y], {x, 2}] + 
      D[z[x, y], {y, 2}] == (a - x/(x^2 + y^2 + 0.00001))*z[x, y] + 
      z[x, y]^3, DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   z, {x, y} ∈ R, 
   InitialSeeding -> {z[x, y] == 0.1 Exp[-(x)^2 - y^2]}];
```

yielding the following:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ndslv[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ R, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16, Black, Italic], 
   Style["y", 16, Black, Italic], Style["z", 16, Black, Italic]}]
```

[image]

One can see that the shapes are very different, but what is even worse, the orders of magnitude differ dramatically. I suppose that this solution is incorrect.

**Now my questions come:**

1. Did I miss something in the formulation of the stationary equation?
2. Should I use any other stationary equation approach that will bring the right solution?
3. In principle, the initial seed suggests that the solver uses an iteration method. May it be that the number of iterations is not enough? Is there a way to control the number of iterations?

I use Mma 12.0, Win. 10.

Any ideas?

**Later edit**
I thank xzczd and user21 for the answers. There is one problem with the idea of xzczd. Namely, if I take increasing seeds, I get different solutions. For example, this

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{lhs == 0, 
       DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
      z[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R, 
      InitialSeeding -> {z[x, y] == #*Exp[-x^2 - y^2]}] & /@ {1., 2, 
     3} // Quiet;
Table[Plot3D[sol1[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] R, ImageSize -> 150, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {x, y, z}), 
  PlotPoints -> 50], {i, 3}]
```

returns the following solutions:

[image]

If the first of them looks like what you have shown in your answer, the others are qualitatively different. Even worth: their amplitude differs from solution to solution. The same takes place if I continue to increase the seed value. I further tried to take the exponent `A*Exp[-x^2-y^2]` as a seed (as I did previously), but increasing `A` in steps. The result is the same.

In this problem, I know at least, qualitatively how the solution should look like. However, in other ones when I do not know anything about the solution I do not see any criterion to decide, where to believe that I am close to the solution.

@ user21: I tried your advice to solve first a linear equation, and then the nonlinear one with the linear solution as a seed. Unfortunately, the linear equation returns `z[x,y]=0`.

Comment: The `Needs["NDSolve\`FEM\`"];` in your code is redundant, unless you actually want to use `ToElementMesh` rather than `DiscretizeRegion`. This is a minimal issue, of course.

Comment: Another unimportant issue is, if `sol[x,y]` is a non-trivial solution, then `-sol[x,y]` is also a solution, so there exist at least 3 solutions :) .

Comment: As a side note, if you use ToElementaMesh the solution will be more accurate then with DiscretizeRegion

Comment: Sometimes what you can do is dove the linear problem (by dropping all nonlinear Trend) and use that as a seed for the nonlinear PDE.

Comment: @xzczd You are right, of course, `-sol[x,y]` is also a solution, qualitatively the same as `sol`.

Comment: @xyzd Please see the edit

Comment: @user21 Please see the edit.

Comment: Reply to the **Later edit**: In _v12.3_ it's not a problem, because `NDSolve` spits out the warning `FindRoot::dfmin` and `NDSolveValue::fempsf`, and returns unevaluated for `2` and `3` :) .

Comment: @user21 Is there a possibility to control the number of iterations?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, you can. By specifying MaxIterations. But I doubt this is what you are looking for. MaxIterations is no means of direction the search direction of a Newton solver. The only option is to specify a starting value that is sufficiently close to the solution you seek.

Answer (score 6):

Setting a large enough constant `InitialSeeding` for FEM seems to help:

```
a = 0.001;
lhs = With[{z = z[x, y]}, 
   D[z, {x, 2}] + D[z, {y, 2}] - ((a - x/(x^2 + y^2 + 0.00001)) z + z^3)];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
R = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {15, 5}], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1^2];
        
sol = NDSolveValue[{lhs == 0, DirichletCondition[z[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    z, {x, y} ∈ R, InitialSeeding -> {z[x, y] == 0.2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.83371, Null} *)

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ R, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {x, y, z}), PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: A small note: the sign in front of `z^3` is wrong.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It's not, I've added one more pair of `()`. You can press Ctrl+Shift+N to check.