# Solving a nonlinear PDE on a mesh with a variable density

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, meshrefinementfunction, discretizeregion

I would like to solve the following partial differential equation in 2D on a disk with the radius 10 and centered in the coordinates origin:

```
eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == -(1 + y/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y] + 
    u[x, y]^3;
```

with the Dirichlet condition on the disk boundary:

```
dC = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, True];
```

The coefficient of the equation eq in front of `u[x,y]` is coordinate-dependent. Therefore, I need to make the mesh such that the closer to the origin the denser is the mesh:

```
Clear[dr]; 
dr = 
 DiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices]; 
     If[x^2 + y^2 > 70, area > 10, 
      If[x^2 + y^2 > 20, area > 5, 
       If[x^2 + y^2 > 1, area > 0.1, area > 0.01]]]]]];
```

That's how the region looks like:

```
Row[{Show[dr, ImageSize -> 250], 
  Show[dr, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, ImageSize -> 250]}]
```

[image]

The left panel is the whole image, while the right one is its central portion.

That's how I planned to solve it:

```
nds = NDSolve[{eq, dC}, u, {x, y} \[Element] dr]
```

However, it does not work. The message is that the minimal damping factor 1/10000 has been reached and NDSolve could not find the solution.

What do I do wrong?

Any idea how to do it another way around?

Comment: @chris What is pb?

Comment: @chris I understand. Unfortunately, the nonlinear term is important. It should be left as it is.  Of course, it is the nonlinearity that gives rise to problems. That's I know, but this equation should be solved as it is formulated.

Comment: Happy new year! If you don't mind, I'd use this example in a message ref page for FindRoot:dfmin?

Comment: @user21 Happy New Year to you also. Of course, use it. It is Ginzburg-Landau equation with a variable coefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transformation `u[x,y]->1+v[x,y]` enables a solution without `InitialSeeding`:

```
V = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[
     v[x, y], {x, 
      y}] == (-(1 + y/(x^2 + y^2)) (1 + v[x, y]) +  (1 + 
         v[x, y])^3)  , DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  v, {x, y} \[Element] dr]
Plot3D[V[x, y] + 1, {x, y} \[Element] dr]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Setting a large enough constant `InitialSeeding` for FEM seems to help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273880/1871) :D :

```
nds = NDSolveValue[{eq, dC}, u, {x, y} ∈ dr, InitialSeeding -> u[x, y] == 0.7];

Plot3D[nds[x, y], {x, y} ∈ dr]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Both answers from xzczd and Ulrich are just fine. In order to find an initial seeding, it's often useful to solve a linear version of the problem. In this case I removed the nonlinear components and the source term and used the solution of that as an initial seed for the full equations:

```
initalSeed = 
  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, dC}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] dr];
Plot3D[initalSeed, {x, y} \[Element] dr]
```

[image]

And then:

```
nds = NDSolveValue[{eq, dC}, u, {x, y} \[Element] dr, 
   InitialSeeding -> u[x, y] == initalSeed];
Plot3D[nds[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] dr]
```

[image]

There still might be some fiddling needed. For example strictly speaking removing the nonlinear terms we'd be left with:

```
Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == -(1 + y/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y]
```

While the linear equation solves fine the nonlinear equation with this seed has the same problem as the original PDE.

While in this case the initial seed is a constant it may not be so in other cases and I wanted to share this approach.

As a side note: One can use `ToElementMesh` in place of the `DiscretizeRegion` to get a second order accurate discretization of the region.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you only took a part of the linear version of the equation. The full one would be: `Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == -(1 + y/(x^2 + y^2))*u[x, y]`. However, if I take this to get the initial seed, the linear equation solves nicely, but the nonlinear does not. It leaves the same message as that I described in my question.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, yes, true, so there is some fiddling. Too bad.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: My choice of the `DiscretizeRegion`, rather that `ToElementMesh` was related to the possibility to use the `MeshRefinementFunction` option of the `DiscretizeRegion`. I am not aware of such a possibility in the approach based on `ToElementMesh`. Did I miss something?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, `ToElementMesh` also has [MeshRefinementFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html#1833277044) option :)

Comment: @Domen Do you know, if it is possible to transform a `DiscretizeRegion` into a mesh object?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, if I understand correctly you can call ToElementMesh[MeshRegion[...]], is that what you are looking for? In essence it's better to generate ToElementMesh from the region directly because then an accurate second order mesh can be formed.

Comment: @user21 OK, I've got it. The solution with such a mesh will be better?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, there is [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#1987775913) section in the documentation that is relevant. If anything is unclear let me know.